# Python exception hook

Tags: python, exception

I want to capture all uncaught exceptions and send the error data to a service. I thought I could just use `sys.excepthook` to do this, but it turns out this hook is never invoked in many cases, e.g. when an uncaught exception occurs in a Flask app.

Is there any low-level hook that I can use to capture uncaught exceptions regardless of where the Python code is running or am I out of luck?

Comment: Maybe the "uncaught" exception are already caught by `Flask`?

Comment: This looks like a job for Flask's Error Handlers ... http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers

Comment: I was hoping to build a more generic library, rather than having to write something specific to Flask, but it's starting to look like I don't have any other options.

Comment: @TylerTreat -- You can build your flask handler handle what you want and then in a "more generic" library, you use `sys.excepthook` to call the same function that you're having flask call.  It's more modular that way anyhow.